# google speech transcribe-streaming-audio with single_utterance and time limit

Tags: google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I am new to the google speech-to-text api. I followed the tutorial on how to transcribe the audio from a microphone stream and it works fine, of course.

My problem arises when I want to use the 'single_utterance' mode, that is, stopping the streaming when the server has detected the end of the user's speech utterance and expects no additional speech.

The code below, manages to retrieve the command from the user most of the times. Sometimes however, no utterance is recognized and the code got stucked in the main for

```
self.get_logger().debug('GSTTService Incoming request')
        
        timer_period=30 # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback(sResponse))
        self.timer.cancel()


        if sRequest.data == True:

            with MicrophoneStream(RATE, CHUNK) as stream:
                audio_generator = stream.generator()
                requests = (
                    speech.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
                    for content in audio_generator
                )
                self.get_logger().debug('requests created')
                responses = self.client.streaming_recognize(self.streaming_config, requests)
                self.get_logger().debug('responses created')
                # Now, put the transcription responses to use.
                #listen_print_loop(responses)
                #sResponse.message = self.__retrieve_text(responses)
                #sResponse.success = True
                
                #start_time = time.time()
                timer.reset()
                self.get_logger().info('start_time')
                timeout_seconds = 30
                final_transcript_received = False

                try:
                    for response in responses:
                        self.get_logger().info('responses loop')
                        if time.time() - start_time > timeout_seconds:
                            self.get_logger().error("Timeout: No final result after %d seconds." % timeout_seconds)
                            sResponse.success = False
                            sResponse.message = "timeout"
                            break  # Exit the loop if we've reached the timeout without a final result

                        # Check if there are any results in this response
                        if not response.results:
                            continue

                        # The first result is the most relevant for single utterance mode
                        result = response.results[0]

                        # Check if the result is final
                        if result.is_final:
                            final_transcript_received = True
                            # Extract the top alternative of the final result
                            top_transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript
                            self.get_logger().info(f"Final transcript: {top_transcript}")
                            sResponse.success = True
                            sResponse.message = top_transcript
                            break  # Exit the loop since we've received a final transcript

                    if not final_transcript_received:
                        self.get_logger().error("No final transcript received.")
                        sResponse.success = False

                except Exception as e:
                    self.get_logger().error(f"Error during speech recognition: {e}")
                    sResponse.success = False
                    return sResponse

                self.get_logger().debug('GSTTService complete request')
            
                return sResponse

            sResponse.success = False
            sResponse.message = "No final result was obtained."
            self.get_logger().info('No final result was obtained.')
            return sResponse

        else:
            sResponse.success = False
            sResponse.message = "The service must be called with 'True' to start recognition."
            return sResponse
```

I am struggling to set a time limit to the server in order to recover from this case when no user utterance is detected.
The streaming config is the following

```
self.streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=self.config,
            single_utterance=True,
            #enable_voice_activity_events=True, voice_activity_timeout=True, speech_end_timeout=10
        )
```

I also tried to disable the last comment but it seems that speech_end_timeout is not recognized as parameter.

Thank you everyone!

I tried to use this code to block the streaming after some timeout but it doens't work